# Creating an Image Popup in Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I'm trying to write a very basic Kivy program that will have an image popup if the right user input is given. I had one image I'm using to test with, but I keep getting the error

"pygame.error: couldn't load cattemp.jpg"

The image is in the same directory as the file, so I know that's not the issue.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.image import Image

def test():
    popup = Popup(title='Test popup',
        content=Image('cattemp.jpg').texture,
        size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try the absolute path of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only load `PNG`.
Use `PIL` to convert the file or use another.

Create your image with something like:

```
import PIL
im = PIL.Image.open('cattemp.jpg')
im.save('cattemp.png')
```

Then you use the image in your program

```
content=Image('cattemp.png').texture,
...
```

Can't load doesn't necessarily mean it's not found.

Comment: Thank you! Does the "im" then go in the popup command? Or does this replace popup entirely? I'm still getting an error that "cattemp" is not defined.